VBA Excel to create email and attached .eml email inside the email error
I tried to send email with eml. email attachment inside.
However, the email attachment was failed to be downloaded and cannot be open.
this .eml file was downloaded by power automate.
Here is the error inside the email:

Sub kirimemail()
 Dim BodyHTML As String
 Dim DirSig As String
 Dim FileNameSig As String
 Dim Pos1 As Long
 Dim Pos2 As Long
 Dim SigHTML As String

    
    
    BodyHTML = "<table border=0 width=""100%"" style=""Color: #000000""" & _
         " bgColor=#FFFFFF><tr><td>Dear all,<br><br>Please help kindly to review and approve the following form" & _
         "<br>Thank you.<br><br>Best Regards,</td></tr></table><br>"
         BodyHTML = BodyHTML
    
' On Error GoTo salah
 
        
nmfile = "Template Remittance  " & ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Raw Data from email").Range("B2").Value
nmpath = ThisWorkbook.Path
nmfile2 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Raw Data from email").Range("F2").Value
 
 Dim objOutlook As Object
 Set objOutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

 
 With objOutlook.createitem(0)
  .Recipients.Add "xxxx@xxx.com"
  .CC = "xxxx@xxx.com"
  .Subject = "Approval for document"
  .Attachments.Add ThisWorkbook.Path & "/" & nmfile & ".PDF"
  .Attachments.Add ThisWorkbook.Path & "/Email source" & nmfile2 & ".eml"
  .HTMLBody = BodyHTML
'  .Body = "Please help to approve " & vbCrLf & "baris kedua" & vbCrLf & "baris ketiga"
  .Display    'Jiks ditsmpilksn dulu
  '.Send        'Langsung kirim
 End With

Please kindly help.
Thank you.

"path does not exist" but there's no way for us to know why that is...   Is ThisWorkbook.Path an HTTP path?

If Email source is a folder then try .Attachments.Add ThisWorkbook.Path & "/Email source/" & nmfile2 & ".eml"
